# How to stop Callable tasks in Executor service if exception occur

Tags: java, spring, concurrency, executorservice, java.util.concurrent

I'm trying to implement a sample application to test Callable and ExecutorService interfaces.

In my app I have:

```
@Bean("fixedThreadPool")
public ExecutorService fixedThreadPool() {
    return Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
}
```

Then:

```
public void removeUserIds(Set<String> userIds) {
 UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString("http://localhost:8080/remove");
    final List<Callable<String>> callables = new ArrayList<>();  
    userIds.forEach(userId -> {
        final Callable<String> task = () -> callServiceToRemove(builder,userId); //Call to remote service using RestTemplate
        callables.add(task);
    });

    try {
        final List<Future<String>> futureList =
            executor.invokeAll(callables);

        futureList.forEach(future -> {
            try {
                log.info(future.get());
            } catch (final Exception e) {
                log.error("Error : "+ e.getMessage());
            } 
        });
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        log.error("Error Error Error : "+ e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        executor.shutdown();
    }
}
```

When I am calling removeUserIds() method with 100 userIds, It is working fine in happy flow, but if service is unavailable  or down, error is getting printed 100th time. I am not able to stop/terminate thread if service is unavailable  or down, so further call will not happen to service. 
Could any one help here to fix this issue, how I can stop thread execution if service is down, or suggest feasible solution here?

Comment: Is your problem that if the service is down, none of the submitted tasks should get executed eventhough they have been submitted to ```ExecutorService```?

Comment: @SreeKumar Yes, similar to that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a more a design problem than a coding issue. There may be several approaches. You may take this one for example:

### **Use a global flag**

Look for a global boolean flag, say `Globals.serviceUnavailable`, before actually firing the remote service call. **This global flag can be set by the first service(s) that encounter the remote error.** Here are the changes to the code.

```
final Callable<String> task = () -> {
   try{    
       if( !Globals.serviceUnavailable ) callServiceToRemove(builder,userId);
   }
   catch( ServiceUnavailableException e ){ //Or whatever your exception is
       Globals.serviceUnavailable = true; //Notify the remaining tasks that the service is unavailable.
   }

}
```

Of course, you will have to see if updating the value of `Globals.serviceUnavailable` has to be synchronized. (It may not be necessary if you are OK for a partial success of removal of the batch of user Ids.)

Also, this will work only if your thread pool is much smaller than the number of submitted tasks, which I see is the case here.

Comment: Used executor.shutdownNow(); in catch block with you suggested code, now  future.get() values are not getting printed 100 times if service is unavailable. Thank you!

Comment: @AnkushNagapure Nice to know! A suggestion: If possible use ```ExecutorService.shutdown()``` and then ```ExecutorService.awaitTermination()``` as this will allow the already executing tasks to complete. This might be useful in the case of a batch of 5 requests some of which could successfully connect and are waiting for the server response, while some others failed. You may want to think of that scenario.

Comment: I have added above code in Spring boot scheduler, now scheduler is not executing after every 1 min as per configuration. I think its because of ExecutorService.shutdown() method. Is that true?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't worked on SpringBoot schedulers. But, in general, if it is using the ```ExecutorService``` that you supplied, on which you called ```shutdown()```, then it may be so. An ```ExecutorService``` instance cannot be reused once ```shutdown()``` or ```shutdownNow()``` has been called on it.

Answer (score 1):

move the callServiceToRemove call inside try catch block.

In the catch block you can use executor.shutdownNow();

**shutdownNow()** attempts to stop all actively executing tasks, halts the processing of waiting tasks, and returns a list of the tasks that were awaiting execution.
This method does not wait for actively executing tasks to terminate and tries to stop them forcefully. There are no guarantees beyond best-effort attempts to stop processing actively executing tasks. This implementation cancels tasks via Thread.interrupt(), so any task that fails to respond to interrupts may never terminate.

Comment: if  the requests are failing simultaneously then you will get error logs for all the failed logs. Try to run in debug mode and pause one thread as check.

Comment: Used shutdownNow() in catch block by enclosing callServiceToRemove(builder,userId); method in try-catch(), now and it is working. Thanks for your response.

Comment: will modify the answer.