# How to run Spring boot scheduler even after executor.shutdownNow(); statement execute

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, executorservice, java.util.concurrent

I'm trying to implement a Spring boot scheduler to test Callable and ExecutorService interfaces.

In my app I have:

```
@Bean("fixedThreadPool")
public ExecutorService fixedThreadPool() {
return Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
}
```

Then:

```
 **@Scheduled(fixedRate = 60000)**
public void removeUserIds(Set<String> userIds) {
UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString("http://localhost:8080/remove");
final List<Callable<String>> callables = new ArrayList<>();  
userIds.forEach(userId -> {
    final List<Callable<String>> callables = new ArrayList<>();
    userIds.forEach(userId -> {
        final Callable<String> task = () -> {
            try{    
                    log.info("Calling service to remove user id node : "+userId);
                    callServiceToRemoveNode(url,userId);
            } catch(ServiceException e ){ 
                log.error("Error while calling service: "+e.getCause());
                **executor.shutdownNow();**

            }
            return "";
        }; //Call to remote service using RestTemplate
    callables.add(task);
});

try {
    final List<Future<String>> futureList =
        executor.invokeAll(callables);

    futureList.forEach(future -> {
        try {
            log.info(future.get());
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            log.error("Error : "+ e.getMessage());
        } 
    });
} catch (final Exception e) {
    log.error("Error Error Error : "+ e.getMessage());
} finally {
    executor.shutdown();
}
}
```

When I am calling removeUserIds() method with 100 userIds, It is working fine in happy flow, but if service is unavailable or down, error is getting printed 100th time and to avoid this I have used  executor.shutdownNow(); so that further call will not happen to service for other user ids. But scheduler is not working and not executing after time interval if **executor.shutdownNow();** statement executes. Could you please help me here to find out solution to avoid scheduler shutdown so even after executor.shutdownNow(); statement executes in before run of scheduler, it should run? or suggest feasible solution here?

Comment: Why are you even shutting down the executor?You shouldn't as spring should do that when the application closes.

Comment: @M.Deinum I am calling remote service in my code using ExecutorService, if service will be unavailable or down, I am forcefully shutting down Executor service for my project requirement. You can refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59839572/how-to-stop-callable-tasks-in-executor-service-if-exception-occur here. But it is shutting down Spring boot scheduler as well.

Comment: Ofcourse it is shutting down because the spring boot scheduler is the scheduler you are using.

Comment: Is there any way to shutdown/stop only Executor running in method instead Spring boot Scheduler?

Comment: No as the executor in the method IS the scheduler configured in Spring Boot. That is the whole point of defining that scheduler as a bean.